# Faraday gem undefined method 'bytesize'=' for Hash`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faraday

I want to send a POST request to an API. Here's my code:

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: BASE) do |faraday|
  faraday.response :logger
  faraday.request  :url_encoded
  faraday.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  faraday.headers["Authorization"] = "bearer #{AppConfig.instance.access_token}"
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
form_data = {a: 1, b: 2}
conn.post("/api/test", form_data)
```

But I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `bytesize' for {:a=>1, :b=>2}:Hash)
```

I've also tried:

```
conn.post("/api/test", form_data.to_json)
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: This is a nice library for making HTTP requests in ruby: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: This error is may be because of the `form_data` is not in proper json format.

Comment: The result of `to_json` definitely responds to `bytesize`: `form_data.to_json.respond_to?(:bytesize) #=> true`

Comment: Should be fine. Just tried to make a post request with your setup and everything was ok. `conn.post("https://google.com/api/test", {a: 1, b: 2}.to_json)` => `#<Faraday::Response:0x00007fe66b9f5a20 ...>`

Comment: What happens when you run your second code (the one with `form_data.to_json`) – do you get the same error or another one?

Answer (score 7):

Official [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) repo provides next description:

```
# post payload as JSON instead of "www-form-urlencoded" encoding:
conn.post do |req|
  req.url '/nigiri'
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = '{ "name": "Unagi" }'
end
```

So, content type 'application/json' can't resolve hash. Gem doesn't convert the body data to needed format by itself.

You need to convert your form_data to string(`json`) format:

```
form_data = {a: 1, b: 2}.to_json
```

Note. Don't convert by `.to_s` when using symbol keys format because that will cause the parsing error.

With provided by you faraday configuration I can't cause any error after converting format_data to json. So, new error not related to faraday gem or provided code.

Comment: _"cause the parsing error"_ / _"new error not related to faraday"_ – which other error are you referring to?

Comment: "which other error are you referring to?" - there is no any other error

Comment: NOTE: faraday now supports `req.request :json` which will serialize the body automatically without having to convert it yourself
https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/#/middleware/included/json

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_json` to convert it to json, It fails with `as_json` as well.

```
{ key: value }.as_json.respond_to?(:bytesize) => false

{ key: value }.to_json.respond_to?(:bytesize) => true
```